# How to prevent undeploying applications in Tomcat Apache 7

Tags: java, tomcat

I am getting one problem [image]

**I want to hide undeploy option**

Is it possible ? If so please help me out.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to set different roles for the `deploy` and `undeploy` operations.

First, register the roles in `$TOMCAT_DIR/conf/tomcat-users.xml`. For example:

```
<role rolename="deploy"/>
<role rolename="undeploy"/>
```

Then, open the `$TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml` and ensure the following:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Manual Deployment</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/html/deploy</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
     <role-name>manager-gui</role-name>
     <role-name>deploy</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Manual Deployment</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/html/undeploy</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>manager-gui</role-name>
    <role-name>undeploy</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This will allow **only** the users which have a `undeploy` role to undeploy applications and only the users who have `deploy` role to deploy applications. Note that an user can be decorated with more than on role.

Finally, decorate your user with some of the newly created roles, restart Tomcat and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer.... Now let me checkout with my server... I will be back shortly and will select your reply as answer.